# Transport rule - siganture modyfication

Tags: ms-office, exchange-server, signature, office365

I have try to standardize signature in my company.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  >
<head>
<style type="text/css">
h1 {font-size: 14pt; font-family: "Segoe UI", Arial,sans-serif; color:#F79646;margin-bottom:0;font-weight:normal;}
h2 {font-size: 11pt; font-family: "Segoe UI", Arial,sans-serif;margin-bottom:1em;margin-top:0;font-weight:normal;}
.email {font-size: 10pt; font-family: "Segoe UI", Arial, sans-serif; color:blue;text-decoration:underline;}
p {font-size: 10pt; font-family: "Segoe UI", Arial, sans-serif; margin-bottom:0;margin-top:0;}
.nazwafirmy {font-size:12pt; font-family: 'Segoe UI', Arial, sans-serif; margin-bottom:0;margin-top:0; color:#F79646;}
a {text-decoration:underline; color:blue;}
.danefirmy {color:#A6A6A6;}
.danefirmy b {color:gray; font-weight:normal;}
.infoprawne {font-size:8pt; color:#A6A6A6;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<br /><br />
<p>Pozdrawiam,</p>
<h1>%%displayname%%</h1>
<h2>%%title%%</h2>
<p class="email">%%email%%</p>
<p>%%mobilenumber%%</p><br />
</p>
</body>
 </html>
```

Everything is working fine and the information is added when the message is sent. But there is one proble: When I send the first email the signature is ok – it’s on the bottom of the email message. When somebody sends me a message and I answer it, the signature will be added on the bottom of this message – not above on the message that was sent to me.

Example:

```
<My answer.>

-----------------------------------------

<Message sent to me.>
<Email Signature>

-----------------------------------------

<My signature answer.>
```

I tried to use "Prepend" but this is the result:

```
<SIGNATURE>
<Message>
```

Is there any solution to configure the transport rule, so that the signature will be added above the message that I answer and not below it when I answer an email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's not a way to do this. I would look at a third party app like Exclaimer - http://www.exclaimer.com/products/signature-manager/default.aspx.

Comment: I think you have right. But I have used rule to stop this signature. It's not prefect but works :)